# Global ping when a post is voted on or badged up from any Stack Exchange site

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, notifications

How about something similar to, or an extension of, the Stack Exchange network notifier where it lets me know if I have gathered new votes on a post (up or down) or a shiny new badge on any of the Stack Exchange sites I have a profile on?

Maybe even drop up this notification along where we currently are pinged of comment and answer replies, or another spot altogether.

For example, when I'm cruising down the freeway in the hot, hot sun of Stack Overflow and I get an upvote at Seasoned Advice, I want to know if this fresh new boat of reputation landing in my dock.

Comment: @Arjan I think the OP is saying "I just received a new privilege (or badge) on one Stack Exchange site, and I would like to be notified about this on all sites." Like the inbox for comments, but for other things.

Answer (score 1):

I often log into a site after some time, only to find out that I have earned some privileges or badges. It's not a bad idea to notify users of those globally. After all, it's not like most users earn badges every day and there are only a couple dozen privileges, so it wouldn't spam you with messages.